# Search Query not accurate enough

Tags: php, search, sqlite

I have a search query done by me to the best of my knowledge in `PHP` but there are some improvements required:

1. When I search say 'what is food' and I have 'what is food' in the database all results containing one of the keywords 'what', 'is', 'food' are shown. The desired behaviour is to display results containing the exact phrase 'what is food' (first)
2. Only the last word in the query is highlighted and I want to highlight all words

Desired behaviour: The right answer shows at the top, regardless of its position in the database.

My current code is like this:

```
if (isset($_GET["mainSearch"]))
{
  $condition = '';
  $mainSearch = SQLite3::escapeString($_GET['mainSearch']);
  $keyword = $_GET['mainSearch'];
  $query = explode(" ", $keyword);
  $perpageview=7;

  if ($_GET["pageno"])
  {
      $page=$_GET["pageno"];
  }
  else
  {
      $page=1;
  }

  $frompage = $page*$perpageview-$perpageview;

  foreach ($query as $text)
  {
      $condition .= "question LIKE '%".SQLite3::escapeString($text)."%' OR answer LIKE '%".SQLite3::escapeString($text)."%' OR ";
  }
  foreach ($query as $text_2)
  {
      $condition_2 .= "bname LIKE '%".SQLite3::escapeString($text_2)."%' OR bankreq LIKE '%".SQLite3::escapeString($text_2)."%' OR ";
  }

  $condition = substr($condition, 0, -4);
  $condition_2 = substr($condition_2, 0, -4);


  $order = " ORDER BY quiz_id DESC ";
  $order_2 = " ORDER BY id DESC ";
  $sql_query = "SELECT * FROM questions WHERE " . $condition . ' '. $order.' LIMIT '.$frompage.','.$perpageview;
  $sql_query_count = "SELECT COUNT(*) as count FROM questions WHERE " . $condition .' '. $order;
  //$mainAnswer = "SELECT * FROM questions WHERE question LIKE '%$mainSearch%' or answer LIKE '%$mainSearch%'";
  $bank_query = "SELECT * FROM banks WHERE " . $condition_2 . ' LIMIT 1';
  $result = $db->query($sql_query);
  $resultCount = $db->querySingle($sql_query_count);
  $bankret = $db->query($bank_query);
  //$mainAnsRet = $db->query($mainAnswer);
  $pagecount = ceil($resultCount/$perpageview);

  if ($resultCount > 0)
  {
  if ($result && $bankret)
  {
      while ($row = $result->fetchArray(SQLITE3_ASSOC))
      {

          $wording = str_replace($text, "<span style='font-weight: bold; color: #1a0dab;'>".$text."</span>", $row['answer']);

           echo '<div class="quesbox_3">
            <div class="questitle">
                <h2>'.$row["question"].'</h2>
            </div>
            <div class="quesanswer">'.$wording.'</div>
        </div>';
      }
      while ($brow = $bankret->fetchArray(SQLITE3_ASSOC))
      {
            $bname = $brow['bname'];
            $bankbrief = $brow['bankbrief'];
            $bankreq = $brow['bankreq'];
            $bankaddress = $brow['bankaddress'];
            $banklogo = $brow['banklogo'];
            $founded = $brow['founded'];
            $owner = $brow['owner'];
            $available = $brow['available'];


           echo '<div class="modulecontent">
            <div class="modulename">
                <div class="mname">'.$bname.'</div>
                <div class="mlogo"><img src="'.$banklogo.'"></div>
            </div>';

            if (strlen($bankreq) > 300)
            {
                $bankcut = substr($bankreq, 0, 300);

                $bankreq = substr($bankcut, 0, strrpos($bankcut, ' ')).'... <a href="bankprofile.php?bname='.$bname.'">Read More</a>';
                echo '<div class="modulebrief">'.$bankreq.'</div>';
            }
            echo '<div class="modulelinks">
                <div class="mfound">Founded: <span>'.$founded.'</span></div>
                <div class="mowned">Ownd By: <span>'.$owner.'</span></div>
            </div>
        </div>';

               // <div class="mavailable">Available for Export Loan: <span>'.$available.'</span></div>
      }
      ?>
      <div class="page_num">
      <?php
      for ($i=1; $i <= $pagecount; $i++) {
         echo '<a href="searchresult.php?mainSearch='.$mainSearch.'&pageno='.$i.'">'.$i.'</a>';
      }
      ?>
      </div>
      <?php
  }
  }
  else
  {
      $session_n = $_SESSION['log_id'];
      $sesdate = date('d/M/Y');
      echo "<div class='searchNone'><p>No results found</p></div>
      <div class='sendSearchQ'>
      <p>Please send us your question.</p>
      <form action='sendquestion.php' method='post' encytype='multipart/form-data'>
      <div class='searchQinputs'>
          <input type='text' name='searchQuestion' id='searchQuestion'placeholder='Whats your question'><br>
          <input type='submit' name='sendQuestion' id='sendQuestion' value='Send'>
          <input type='text' name='user' id='user' value='$session_n' style='display: none'>
          <input type='text' name='qDate' id='qDate' value='$sesdate' style='display: none'>
          <input type='text' name='status' id='status' value='0' style='display: none'>
          </div>
      </form>
      </div>";
  }
}
```

Comment: try adding `= $mainSearch or like %$mainSearch%` to both conditions

Comment: @diagold, what is your expected resutl by and also your table structure both thing can you add in your question

Comment: You ought to consider using MySQL's [Full-Text Search Functions](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/fulltext-search.html), or else use a search engine like [Solr](https://lucene.apache.org/solr/) or [Sphinx](http://sphinxsearch.com/).

Comment: It seems to me this question just needs to provide the code for one table to be answered. Having two (`question` and `banks`) adds an unnecessary complexity to the question. Please provide minimal code.

Comment: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/fulltext-natural-language.html

Comment: i would stop using SQLite if you want advanced searches don't use a minimal DB system such as SQLite move your code over to using MySQL, MSSQL (SQL Server), you can then use as @juergeen pointed out FullText searching otherwise you might be doing a lot of string parsing and building a search query syntax E.G `"Word1 Word2"`, (one after the other) `Word1 | Word2`(Word 1 or Word 2 but not both), `Word1 & Word2` (Word 1 & Word 2 in the same row)

Comment: my initial answer was for `MySQL` it is now corrected for `SQLite3`. I think it is exactly what you need, based on how you defined accuracy in this question. Not only you will get best match first but results will be sorted by the amount of keywords found.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

## Add a sortable field to your query

#### First we need to simplify your problem

Your problem can be treated as a simple keyword match, where the top results must match all keywords as entered.

A Search for: `some search text` should return all results containing any of those words `['some', 'search', 'text']`, with results at the top matching *exactly as entered* `"some search text"`.

This means you'll need to create an aggregate field that allows the result to be sorted based on a match. The only way I know to do this, without refactoring data and/or code, is with a [MySql Case](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/case.html) statement.

#### Your Query Simplified

```
SELECT *
FROM questions
WHERE
    question LIKE '%[word1]%' OR answer LIKE '%[word1]%'
    OR question LIKE '%[word2]%' OR answer LIKE '%[word2]%'
    OR question LIKE '%[word3]%' OR answer LIKE '%[word3]%'
ORDER BY quiz_id DESC
```

### Case [full-match] and Sort

What we need to build is a query that looks a bit like this:

```
SELECT *,
    (CASE WHEN
            question LIKE '%[full-search-query]%'
            OR answer LIKE '%[full-search-query]%'
        THEN 1 ELSE 0
    END) as fullmatch
FROM questions
WHERE
    question LIKE '%[word1]%' OR answer LIKE '%[word1]%'
    OR question LIKE '%[word2]%' OR answer LIKE '%[word2]%'
    OR question LIKE '%[word3]%' OR answer LIKE '%[word3]%'
ORDER BY fullmatch DESC, quiz_id DESC
```

### Adjusting your code

```
// your initial storage of the full search, before you split it on spaces
$keyword = $_GET['mainSearch'];

. . .

// build our sorting field
$sortFullMatch = "(CASE WHEN question LIKE '%".SQLite3::escapeString($keyword)."%' OR answer LIKE '%".SQLite3::escapeString($keyword)."%' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as fullmatch";

. . .

// adjust the query and sort
$order = " ORDER BY fullmatch DESC, quiz_id DESC ";
$sql_query = "SELECT *,". $sortFullMatch ." FROM questions WHERE ".$condition.' '.$order.' LIMIT '.$frompage.','.$perpageview;
```

#### What does this do?

We added a new field to the SELECT statement, `fulltext`. When a question or answer contains exactly the full search, this field will be 1, otherwise 0. Then simply sort on this field.

## Highlighting

As for your highlighting issue, you're only replacing on `$text` which is set in a loop on each word in `mainSearch`. Thus, it will only be the last word in the set. Instead, you'll need to do a similar loop here.

#### Your Code

```
$wording = str_replace($text, "<span style='font-weight: bold; color: #1a0dab;'>".$text."</span>", $row['answer']);
```

#### Adjusted

```
foreach($query as $text) {
    $wording = str_replace($text, "<span style='font-weight: bold; color: #1a0dab;'>".$text."</span>", $row['answer']);
}
```

Comment: Thanks but when i implement this i get the `Warning: SQLite3::querySingle(): Unable to prepare statement: 1, no such column: fullmatch in ` erro. Does this mean i hace to add a `fullmatch` column to the database?

Comment: Ok i implemented it to the count query and it still brings out the whole data in the db

Comment: @diagold, Your question was worded to be primarily concerned with ensuring that a full-text-match appeared on top of results. Rewriting your search-engine is OOS for stackoverflow.

Comment: @diagold, Carefully consider what your code is actually doing. 1. Split the search query on spaces. 2. add each word to an `LIKE '%[word]%' OR ...` clause. I suspect _every_ question and answer contains "is." Reviewing how I structured things, and what you really want this script to do, should give you a better idea of which direction to go.

Comment: Works perfectly

Answer (score 3):

You can use Google's NLP apis in order to detect words which are just connnectors and words which are are nounds and have salience, so that the query you send to the database ignores words like "what" or "is" and that way you can provide a much better experience to your users. there are also other tools like NLTK et al which can be also used to make queries smarter.

Answer (score 2):

For performance reason, you should use `REGEXP` instead of multiple `LIKE` instructions. Ordering can be done using a simple `ORDER BY` instruction like the one below:

```
$keyword=$_GET['mainSearch'];
$pattern=join("|", array_filter(explode(" ", $keyword)));

$sql_query="SELECT * FROM questions
     WHERE (question REGEXP '$pattern') OR (answer REGEXP '$pattern')
     ORDER BY CONCAT(question, answer) LIKE '%$keyword%' DESC;";
```

Highlighting can be easily done using `preg_replace`

```
 preg_replace("/($pattern)/",
       "<span style='font-weight: bold; color: #1a0dab;'>$1</span>",
       $row['answer']);
```

Answer (score 1):

First run the below query in your database once.

```
ALTER TABLE  questions  ADD FULLTEXT(question, answer);
```

Then use below query for searching

```
if (isset($_GET["mainSearch"]))
{
  $condition = '';
  $mainSearch = SQLite3::escapeString($_GET['mainSearch']);
  $keyword = $_GET['mainSearch'];
  $query = explode(" ", $keyword);


  $puresearch=implode("*+*", $query);

  $myquery = "SELECT *,MATCH(question,answer) AGAINST('*".$keyword."*' IN BOOLEAN MODE) as relavance FROM questions WHERE MATCH(question,answer) AGAINST('*".$keyword."*' IN BOOLEAN MODE) ORDER BY ralavance DESC";

  $result = $db->query($myquery);

}
```

This is the full text search which gives you results according to relevance and can be arranged in descending order to show the search at first point which is more reliable to the search.

Answer (score 0):

Given this `test` table

```
create table test (
  tid integer PRIMARY KEY,
  ttext text NOT NULL
  );
  INSERT INTO test (
  tid,
  ttext
  ) VALUES (1,'what are you doing?'),(2,'this is your house?'),(3,'food chain'),(4,'what is food');
```

your ending queries should look like this

```
select *,
(case
when ttext like '%food%' then 1
else 0
end+
case
when ttext like '%chain%' then 1
else 0
end) as tsum
from test where ttext like '%food%' or ttext like '%chain%' 
order by tsum desc;

id  text           sum
 3  food chain      2
 4  what is food    1    

select *,
(case
when ttext like '%what%' then 1
else 0
end+
case
when ttext like '%is%' then 1
else 0
end+
case
when ttext like '%food%' then 1
else 0
end) as tsum
from test where ttext like '%what%' or ttext like '%is%' or ttext like '%food%' 
order by tsum desc;

id  text                sum
 4  what is food         3
 1  what are you doing?  1
 2  this is your house?  1
 3  food chain           1

select *,
(case
when ttext like '%this%' then 1
else 0
end+
case
when ttext like '%is%' then 1
else 0
end) as tsum
from test where ttext like '%this%' or ttext like '%is%' 
order by tsum desc;

id  text                sum
 2  this is your house?  2
 4  what is food         1

select *,
(case
when ttext like '%what%' then 1
else 0
end+
case
when ttext like '%is%' then 1
else 0
end+
case
when ttext like '%house%' then 1
else 0
end) as tsum
from test where ttext like '%what%' or ttext like '%is%' or ttext like '%house%' 
order by tsum desc;

id  text                sum
 2  this is your house?  2
 4  what is food         2
 1  what are you doing?  1
```

You can test all the above queries on [DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/uE6NLpFtwkkNUyvXudsnGw/0)

To build this kind of query and given that you are using `PDO`, your `PHP` code should look like this.

```
...
// Sample code for 1st example query
$keywrd1 = '%food%';
$keywrd2 = '%chain%';
// Prepare the command
$sth = $dbh->prepare('select *,
(case
when ttext like :keyword1 then 1
else 0
end+
case
when ttext like :keyword2 then 1
else 0
end) as tsum
from test where ttext like :keyword1 or ttext like :keyword2 
order by tsum desc');
// Bind the parameters
$sth->bindParam(':keyword1', $keywrd1, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$sth->bindParam(':keyword2', $keywrd2, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$sth->execute();
...
```